# No Time /usr/bin/python3: can't open file [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: permissions, cron

I want to automate my python file, but I cannot.
In my crontab:

```
31 01 * * *  /usr/bin/python3 /home/attyan22/python_lesson/crontest_2.py
```

The error:

```
Return-Path: <attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C.com>
X-Original-To: attyan22
Delivered-To: attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C.com
Received: by mx.LAPTOP-SGBTV53C.com (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id 5867B240000000612A3; Sat, 27 Apr 2019 01:31:02 +0900 (DST)
From: root@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C.com (Cron Daemon)
To: attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C.com
Subject: Cron <attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C> /usr/bin/python3 /home/attyan22/python_lesson/crontest_2.py
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/attyan22>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=attyan22>
Message-Id: <20190426163102.5867B240000000612A3@mx.LAPTOP-SGBTV53C.com>
Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2019 01:31:02 +0900 (DST)

/usr/bin/python3: can't open           file '/home/attyan22/python_lesson/crontest_2.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

and rights are:

```
attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C:~$ sudo ls -l /home/attyan22/python_lesson/crontest_2.py
[sudo] password for attyan22:
-rwx--x--x 1 attyan22 attyan22 0 Apr 26 20:24 /home/attyan22/python_lesson/crontest_2.py
attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C:~$ sudo ls -l /home/attyan22/python_lesson/crontest_2.py
-rwx--x--x 1 attyan22 attyan22 0 Apr 26 20:24 /home/attyan22/python_lesson/crontest_2.py
attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 attyan22 attyan22 9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
attyan22@LAPTOP-SGBTV53C:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4522328 Oct 22  2018 /usr/bin/python3.6
```

I want to automate my python program by using cron. how remove this?

OS WSL UBUNTU.

Comment: If you want to launch normal script you have to add `./` in front of the path. In your case I think you should not do this, you should write `python3  /home/attyan22/python_lesson/crontest_2.py`. At least I think so.

Comment: @John Ronald result was same

Comment: Are you placing it in `attyan22`'s crontab (`crontab -e`) or in `root`'s (`sudo crontab -e`)? Only `attyan22` has read permission to the .py file.

Comment: under /var/spool/cron/crontabs/attyan22